# Is there a subsite of stackexchange where I can ask about the interface between different languages?

Tags: discussion

Is there a subsite of stackexchange where I can ask about the interface between different languages? I tried the following question, both it and the inverse (English words in Greek sentences), and it's only been met with, I think, some annoyance.

Maybe, a linguistics site?

> I think that, in a given pronunciation, a word with primary stress on
>   one syllable cannot ever have another syllable stressed instead.
>
> So e.g. the word tomato in RP, has its stress on the second syllable
>
> ```
> /təˈmɑːtəʊ
> ```
>
> And there's no sentence you can write in RP in which it falls on the
>   3rd syllable and not the 2nd.
>
> And the same holds for e.g. the Greek language.
>
> My question is somewhat obscure, apologies.
>
> I want to know if someone can say a Greek word' e.g. φίλος, which has
>   its primary stress on the 1st syllable, in perfectly Greek accent, but
>   stress only the 1st syllable.
>
> Perhaps due to using the word in an otherwise English sentence,
>   coupled with differences in how stress is reflected in English and
>   Greek.

Comment: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com but you'll need to rewrite your question entirely, it doesn't make much sense as is.

Comment: @Mitch hm i can't tell what's making sense. i got a comment, honing in on what i should edit it. i'll see what happens, thanks